# Is exponential even?

Tags: improper-integrals, symmetry

My book presents the following simplification:
$$A(w) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-kx}cos(wx)dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-kx}cos(wx)dx$$
But I can't understand why, since exponentials are neither odd nor even functions. There's something I'm missing ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's nonsense. Maybe it's $e^{-kx^2}$, or $e^{-k|x|}$ or something?

Comment: Maybe you overlooked them, maybe the typesetter forgot them, but there ought to be absolute value bars, $e^{-k\lvert x\rvert}$, or an exponent like $e^{-kx^2}$.

Comment: looking at plots from maple it is clearly not an even function, but you know that when you substitute -x for x.  the cosine function is even, but the exponential function is not (you get $e^{kx}$ instead of $e^{-kx}$ back.

Comment: It would change something if I restric the domain to x > 0 ?

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Advanced Engineering Mathematics, Kreyszig, 10th Edition, pag. 516 on applications of Fourier Integral (Laplace Integrals).

Comment: Ah engineers... ;-)

Comment: @OtávioRapôso I have the book, and there is no such equation on p. 516.

Comment: Not everything is in the page. He says "From (10)..." but (10) is derived from considering that f(x) = exp(-kx) (or any other f(x)) must be even.   
He says, if f(x) is even, then B(w) = 0 in the Fourier integral and A(w) can be doubled with the change in the integral intervals. Then, in the example he uses this to say that if f(x) is exponential, then you can double A(w).

Comment: The trick there is to consider the function $e^{-k|x|}$ for the cosine integral (i.e. part a) (The funny thing is he does not mention it, or I could not see it myself). Then, everything works out as written in the book. For part (b), he considers the function  $e^{-kx}$ for positive $x$ and $-e^{-k|x|}$ for negative $x$. Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is true. I don't think the first integral converges.